# MIPS .data section of the program?

Tags: assembly, mips

I do not understand what the .data section is specifically for? 
Is it comparable to wanting to say y = 8? Couldnt you just load an immediate value of 8 into some register which would be the same?

Comment: I can only offer this link - [MIPS Data and Text Segment](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/dataseg.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's for storing, well, ummm, **data**.

A typical program will have several sections:

- `.text` → for code (program text)
- `.rodata` → for read-only data
- `.data` → for data
- `.bss` → for uninitialized data
- ...

C global variables and static local variables go to `.data` or `.bss` (they get created when loading the program, and get destroyed on program's end, their lifetime is the entire program execution). C local variables go to the stack (they get created when entering the function, and get destroyed when leaving the function), C storage allocated by `malloc()` go to the heap (they get created and destroyed dynamically by the programmer, their lifetime is dynamic).